# How to statically link libusb (1.0) into C++ executable with CMake?

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, mingw-w64, libusb-1.0

Using CLion and CMake (3.12.2) with MinGW (W64 6.0), I am trying to compile a simple 'Stub' executable using some libusb example code.  I would like for the executable to be statically linked, and not require the .dll to be placed alongside it upon execution. Eventually, I would like to statically link on Linux as well, as these executables will run in a cgi-bin.

I've tried linking in libusb-1.0.a included with the libusb files specifically for mingw-w64 with no luck.

Here is the simple example program:

```cpp
// This program was copied from Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B#Language

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <libusb.h>

using namespace std;

static void print_devs(libusb_device **devs) {
    libusb_device *dev;
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    uint8_t path[8];

    while ((dev = devs[i++]) != NULL) {
        struct libusb_device_descriptor desc;
        int r = libusb_get_device_descriptor(dev, &desc);
        if (r < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "failed to get device descriptor");
            return;
        }

        printf("%04x:%04x (bus %d, device %d)",
               desc.idVendor, desc.idProduct,
               libusb_get_bus_number(dev), libusb_get_device_address(dev));

        r = libusb_get_port_numbers(dev, path, sizeof(path));
        if (r > 0) {
            printf(" path: %d", path[0]);
            for (j = 1; j < r; j++)
                printf(".%d", path[j]);
        }
        printf("<br />\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    cout << "Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n";


    libusb_device **devs;
    int r;
    ssize_t cnt;

    r = libusb_init(NULL);
    if (r < 0)
        return r;

    cnt = libusb_get_device_list(NULL, &devs);
    if (cnt < 0) {
        libusb_exit(NULL);
        return (int) cnt;
    }

    // Output HTML boilerplate
    cout << "<!doctype html>\n";
    cout << "<html lang=\"en\">\n";
    cout << "<head>\n";
    cout << "</head>\n";
    cout << "<body>\n";
    cout << "Hello, world!<br />\n\n";
    cout << "Listing USB devices...<br /><br />\n";
    print_devs(devs);
    cout << "</body>\n";
    cout << "</html>";
    libusb_free_device_list(devs, 1);

    libusb_exit(NULL);
    return 0;

}
```

Here is the CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8.4)

# Temporary project
project (Stub)


# Add the stub file for compilation as an executable.
add_executable (Stub stub.cpp)

# Add libraries

if (UNIX)
   target_link_libraries(Stub -L/${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/dependencies/lib/Linux/x64 usb-1.0 udev pthread)
endif (UNIX)

# For windows
if(WIN32)
   link_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/dependencies/lib/windows/x86)
   target_link_libraries(Stub ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/dependencies/libusb-1.0.a ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/dependencies/lib/windows/x86/libusb-1.0.lib)
endif(WIN32)

# Add include directories
target_include_directories(Stub PUBLIC ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/dependencies/include/libusb-1.0)
```

I have tried to remove "target_include_directories", but the build fails, and I end up having to put this back in.  No matter how I tweak it, the build either fails, or the resulting executable is dependent on the .dll when I try to execute it.  On the Linux side of things, I am not sure if the static linking is possible with CMake due to the need for udev. I am completely unfamiliar with CMake and how it works to accomplish this task on both OS halves of my project.

Comment: Description "the build fails" is not useful for asking the help. What **exactly** is happen? Do you got a compiler or a linker error? If yes, **show that error** (add it to the question post). "resulting executable is dependent on the .dll when I try to execute it." - That means that your `.lib` file is actually not a *static* library but is an *export file* for a *dynamic* library.

Comment: @rustyx I did not even think about this. Thanks for the information.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you for your response also

Comment: Note that as at this time of writing (June-2021), `libusb` is licensed under LGPL so you can statically link without necessarily making your code GPL.